Help Distinguishing From Duplicate Question
I'm looking for guidance on a question I posted...
Pointer Aliasing in C++
...that was marked as a duplicate
The original question includes a code sample, in reference to pointer aliasing (a concept), and my intention was to understand how to reason about its behavior.
The linked duplicate question seems to only answer what technically qualifies as pointer aliasing.
How could I have made this distinction more apparent?

This probably isn't the main factor, but you really should choose a more specific title so that people can distinguish your question from others on the subject at a glance.

"my intention was to understand how to reason about its behavior. The linked duplicate question seems to only answer what technically qualifies as pointer aliasing." - I'm not sure why you believe there is an actual distinction here. You appear to be asking why aliasing can't be disproven in a specific code example. When you write ((unsigned char*)b)[i] = 0;, you're type-punning, and using an unsigned char* to do so. The other question asks whether an unsigned char* "may alias anything"; answer: yes, just like char *. Therefore, aliasing can't be disproven.

@KarlKnechtel The question I try to ask at the conclusion of my post: "What sequence of code/events would make the folding invalid?" I've already accepted char* and its variants are able to type alias, which seems to be what the linked question is asking: "Are signed char * and unsigned char * (and their qualified variants) exempt from this?". My question is about the rationale and assumptions the compiler is allowed to make, specifically in that case where the argument types are already signaling they shouldn't alias. Don't those seem like two different questions?

"the rationale and assumptions the compiler is allowed to make, specifically in that case where the argument types are already signaling" - ah, I think then that you've answered the question about how to write the question so that it's clearly distinct.

@KarlKnechtel I've updated the original post to clarify that point - thanks for the tip. Anything else you think could use changing?

I tried to edit the question so that it would flow better and be clearer. Having done so, I think I've seen where you simply misunderstood the article and need to read it again more carefully from the beginning. The compiler needs to know whether aliasing is possible, not to predict whether it actually happens with values the program actually receives. It assumes that aliasing is not possible when aliasing would invoke UB, because that's how UB works. And the type punning changes the assumption because it makes the assignment stop being UB in the aliasing case.

(Notice the part of the original article, after the second code example, where I added that quote - after I noticed that the second code example is from part 2 of the post at a separate URL. In particular: "the function would be valid if called with b equal to a". This is the fact that changes. It becomes valid in this case, because the assignment zeroing out bytes of the underlying long is valid, because of the pointer type used in the assignment. It's not about the function prototype at all.)

All that said, I don't think you duplicate the other Q&A, and I do think you have a valid question (it's just one that some might argue was already answered by the article you found; but there's nothing wrong with duplicating article content on Stack Overflow, especially transforming it into Q&A form.) Perhaps this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650 , but that Q&A needs a better introductory answer. Or maybe a better question title is "How can compilers use the strict aliasing rule to make optimizations?".

@KarlKnechtel The flow of the question has improved much after your edit, and I updated the title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129505/how-do-compilers-use-the-strict-aliasing-rule-to-make-optimizations. My only problem is this line - "Doesn't the function signature signal which of these cases applies" - has changed the original intent. I appreciate your point about the runtime value not mattering to the compiler. Originally I was trying to say both paths are possible, in both foo and bar. I've made an edit to reflect that.

Also re: your previous quote from the article: "the function would be valid if called with b equal to a". I don't actually understand this line. "Valid" means what here? Isn't "b equal to a" just a violation of strict aliasing at the call to bar, subject to UB, and ultimately ignorable by the compiler?

"Valid" means "still does not invoke UB in this circumstance". Again, strict aliasing is not about the function prototype, and is not about what values may be passed to a function. It's about assignment through pointers which alias memory. In the first code block, the compiler doesn't assume no aliasing because of the prototype; it assumes no aliasing because the only assignment, *b = 0, assigns through a pointer type that is incompatible with a. But char * etc. are compatible with every other pointer type.

@KarlKnechtel Sorry, will try to be more precise. The compiler assumes "no aliasing because the only assignment, *b = 0, assigns through a pointer type that is incompatible with a" - understood. Is it safe to say that the compiler can't determine "no aliasing when it assigns through an alias to a pointer whose original type was incompatible with a"?

I attempted to re-ask, and answer, on Codidact. Please see if it helps.

@KarlKnechtel I've read the article and think I have a better understanding now. The compiler essentially treats all pointer types as addresses/void* until the point where that address is dereferenced and/or written. While it may obfuscate intent, no information is lost converting between any two pointer types, so it's technically valid. Once dereferenced, appropriate type considerations (size, alignment) come into play, hence the emphasis on "assignments through pointers" re: aliasing. So the second example has a single, non-UB aliasing assignment. Does that sound reasonable?
